# How to create mutiple single-page-app like behavior in an app using AngularJS nodejs and expressjs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I am working on an application that has a front end and an admin end. The look of the admin end is different than the front end, that is the CSS and JavaScript files being used on front end and admin end are almost different. I have to keep both the ends (front and admin) behave like single page app.

Could somebody guide me with an approach for the same using AngularJS, nodejs, expressjs and angular ui-router or guide me through any existing resources. I am at the beginning of the admin end and I don't want to commit any design blunders doing something I shouldn't.

I load all the CSS and JavaScript files only once each for the front end and the admin end.

It quite new to MEAN stack world.

Comment: @Astro: Did you vote for closing this question? If yes, then why? If no, then how could I see who voted for it to be closed?

Comment: I didn't vote to close but in reading the question it needs severe editing or should be closed.  Stack overflow is meant for specific questions that have specific answers not the right place to ask for tutorials or general help... Try the IRC

Comment: @shaunhusain: What is IRC?

Comment: @shaunhusain: Which part from the post should I remove or replace it with something else to get some guidance or idea on how to approach the issue I explained in the question?

Comment: IRC is internet relay chat just google for a client join #angularjs room there are usually lots of folks to discuss with or to ask for guidance or resources.  SO is just typically quick or at least very specific questions with relatively objective and brief answers.

Comment: @skip Voting to close requires 3k reputation, which I do not yet have. Who voted to close does not really matter; you should be thinking about *why* people voted to close and try to fix your question based on that.